# Workflow: subsequently meet criteria vs ISCHANGED

Tags: trigger, workflow

I have below query to send an email when case is reopened from closed.

```
AND(ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE(Status),"Closed"), 
 OR(ISPICKVAL(Status, "New"),ISPICKVAL(Status, "In Progress"), 
 ISPICKVAL(Status,"Reopened")))
```

But it is not accepting when i give criteria

> created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria

Is there any other way to achieve this when meet this criteria.

It is working with

> created, and every time it’s edited

But i don't want to fire when "
created, and every time it’s edited".

Comment: Can you clarify why you don't want it to fire every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your formula to filter on previous values of fields (`PRIORVALUE`), or any of them being changed (`ISCHANGED`), you cannot also use the `subsequently meets criteria` option.

Your hands are tied, you have to evaluate these criteria every time the record is edited. The criteria will still apply, meaning the actions won't be carried out unless the `Status` changes *from* `"Closed"` *to* one of your whitelisted values.

Comment: Yeah, with everytime edited criteria we may have a problem of firing several times when they changed and meet that criteria again. Is there any other way like writing trigger or something?

Comment: @Frank It would have to be closed again and then reopened again. It only fires if `Status="Closed"` when you commit the edit and change it to a different value. That cannot happen more than once consecutively.